# xcodebuild command line hangs

Tags: xcode, cordova, xcodebuild

The following command hangs on my osx:

```
xcodebuild -scheme myscheme clean archive -archivePath /tmp
```

This command yields two output lines, and then hangs:

```
User defaults from command line:
    IDEArchivePathOverride = /tmp
```

Now, this project does NOT have a workspace generated as it was created from a cordova command line (`cordova build ios`). The only way around it is to open xcode and close it. this generates a workspace and then the above command succeeds.

Did anyone experience something similar and know a way out of this? Any way to generate that workspace from the command line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem and the only way of fixing it was to open the project from the command line, wait, and close it again after a certain time.

```
open "My Project.xcodeproj"
sleep 10
killall Xcode
xcodebuild -scheme "My Project" clean archive "build/MyProject"
```

Not nice, but works for me.

Comment: this is by far the ugliest workaround i've ever coded :)

Comment: I couldn't agree more!

Comment: Truely horrible but only thing that works so far. :( Note: Also for Cordova builds you have to add ENABLE_BITCODE=NO to the config

Answer (score 9):

Try setting the scheme to be 'shared'.

This can be done by going to the 'Manage Schemes...' and checking the 'Shared' checkbox.

Apple documents this process here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeShare.html

Comment: I've just tried it and it works; the problem is that when you're working in a cordova/ionic context the xcodeproj could be deleted and restored (ionic state restore) and the previous configuration is lost.

Comment: Also, confirmed this is working. The answer from @anytoe didn't work for me.

Comment: Nice find, but still needs manual work for every project. So you could also then open it in Xcode manually and then it's sorted. But as soon as you remove the platform iOS and re-add it you have to repeat this step.

Comment: My project's schemes were already shared, but @anytoe's (highly disruptive) workaround worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already have, or are willing to make, Ruby available to your build system then you could [use this solution](http://moduscreate.com/cordova_xcodebuild_hangs_freezes_during_build/).

Install the xcodeproj gem on your build system

```
sudo gem install xcodeproj
```

and then integrate the following ruby script into your project (renaming your xcodeproj path).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'xcodeproj' 
xcproj = Xcodeproj::Project.open("platforms/ios/schemedemo.xcodeproj")
xcproj.recreate_user_schemes
xcproj.save
```

The article explains how to make it part of a cordova hook if you're doing that, I simply called ruby directly from my Jenkins build.

This works because when you recreate the proj files, you destroy the schemes, so you need to recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe xcodebuild hangs because some data is missing from the project. You can make a template for what this data looks like and use a hook to populate it if necessary.

1. cordova add platform ios
2. cordova build ...
3. open platforms/ios/Whatever.xcodeproj in xcode
4. create xcuserdata_template
5. cp -R platforms/ios/Whatever.xcodeproj/xcuserdata xcuserdata_template/
6. replace the unique id in that template with XXXXXXXXXX
7. update your hook that runs xcodebuild

Step 7 example:

```
XCODE_PROJ=path/to/Whatever.xcodeproj

# get the mysterious id
ID=`grep "Whatever \*\/ = {" $XCODE_PROJ/project.pbxproj | \
    grep -io "[-A-Z0-9]\{24\}"`

mkdir -p $XCODE_PROJ/xcuserdata

XCUSERDATAD=$XCODE_PROJ/xcuserdata/`whoami`.xcuserdatad

if [ ! -d "$XCUSERDATAD" ]; then
    cp -R path/to/xcuserdata_template/username.xcuserdatad \
        $XCUSERDATAD
    find $XCUSERDATAD -type f -exec sed -i '' -e "s/XXXXXXXXXX/$ID/g" {} \;
fi

xcodebuild ...
```